# Rails count number data within several records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a column in my database, "occurrences".  The user has the option to enter nothing or any number from 1 to 10.  And I'm trying to add all the occurrences (across several records) for each user into a grand total.

**Part 1 - Filtering data to current user**

```
@total_occurrences = Event.where(['occurrences <> ?', current_user.id])
```

So far so good.

**Part 2 - Counting numbers in column "occurrences"**

Not sure how to approach this...

Answer (score 1):

If you use rails 4 you can write:

```
@total_occurrences = Event.where(user_id: current_user.id).where.not(occurrences: nil)
```

In rails 3 you can write sql query:

```
@total_occurrences = Event.where(user_id: current_user.id).where("occurrences IS NOT NULL")
```

Or use gem [Squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel). It allows you to write like this:

```
@total_occurrences = Event.where{(user_id == current_user.id) & (occurrences != nil)}
```

Answer (score 1):

As for part two, you can do something like this:

```
sum = 0
Event.where(user_id: current_user.id).pluck(:occurrences).each do |occurrence|
  sum += occurrences
end
```

Pluck pulls out all the values of a specific column, then all you have to do is add them together.

Answer (score -1):

brendanjcaffrey's answer is what I'm looking for:

Event.where(user_id: current_user.id).where('occurrences <> 0').pluck(:occurrences).sum

Comment: Your where clause is checking that occurrences != current_user.id. Are you sure that's what you're trying to do? Try `Event.where(user_id: current_user.id).where('occurrences <> 0').pluck(:occurrences).sum`.